# ¿Como buscar la ruta de un app por su nombre?

Tags: java, android

Quiero buscar la ruta de un app mediante su nombre, he buscado e investigado y el metodo PackageManager parece el ideal pero no se como adaptarlo para que haga lo deseado.

Comment: dentro de tu app, quieres buscar rutas de otras app mediante su nombre?? o quieres encontrar la ruta de tu misma app?

Comment: De otras app desde la mía. Si sabe algo por favor ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un método que yo cree, el cual por medio del nombre de la aplicación se obtiene el directorio de datos de la aplicación.

```
private String getPathFromAppname(String appName){
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    String applicationPath = "";
    final List<PackageInfo> listadoPackages =  getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i=0; i < listadoPackages.size(); i++)
    {
        PackageInfo packInfo = listadoPackages.get(i);
        if (  (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)
        {
            if(appName.equals(packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString())) {
                //String nombreApplicacion = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                //Log.i("Nombre de aplicación: " + Integer.toString(i), nombreApplicacion);
                //String paqueteApplicacion = packInfo.packageName;
                Log.i("packagename: " + Integer.toString(i), paqueteApplicacion);
                applicationPath = packInfo.applicationInfo.dataDir;
                Log.i("sourceDir: " + Integer.toString(i), packInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
            }
        }
    }
    return applicationPath;
}
```

Un ejemplo de como llamarlo:

```
Log.i("Path: ", getPathFromAppname("[Nombre de Aplicación]"));
```

**Es importante comentar que puedes tener instaladas varias aplicaciones con el mismo nombre en tu dispositivo, por lo tanto lo correcto es usar el `PackageName` (alias id de aplicación) el cual es único, en cambio los nombres desplegados por la aplicación NO.**